# Is it faster to use DB's column ordering with SELECT * than specifying it manually?

Tags: postgresql

I often run very large SELECTs where every millisecond per row translates to minutes or hours for a query. Thus the question - assuming that I'm going to fetch all columns anyway, is it faster to run `SELECT *` than specifying the ordering manually?

Comment: " every millisecond translates to minutes or hours for a query. ".  I just cannot fathom what this statement really means.  Are you in some sort of time warp?

Comment: If the differences are *that* obvious… how about benchmarking the difference?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I meant that every millisecond per row, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably focusing on exactly the *wrong* thing.  Such micro-optimizations are not usually an issue when using SQL.  There are often really big improvements, by understanding the query.

What you would be referring to is the translation of the record from the data page to the output format.  Postgres is going to have to do this transformation regardless of the ordering of the columns.  There is some effort (for instance, `NULL` values have to be handled regardless), but unless you are working with some really archaic very slow processor, milliseconds are the wrong unit by orders of magnitude.

There is an issue, if some columns are very wide.  In this case, removing them from the `SELECT` can save effort.  If this is the case, the saved effort is probably more noticeable in returning the data to the application, rather than in the Postgres parsing itself.